# Como utiliza Range Slider para imagens

Tags: php, slider

Eu tenho um site de venda de carros para fazer, mas estou com dificuldades na parte de filtros onde preciso de preço máximo e preço mínimo, então fiz pela primeira vez um range slider mas não consigo fazer com que reduza as opções de carros ao diminuir o preço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ficam sempre todos os carros como faço para ficar apenas os carros com o preço dentro dos limites?

```
<?php
        include 'conn.php';
        mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf-8");

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT preco from carros_desc where preco = (SELECT preco FROM carros_desc ORDER BY preco ASC LIMIT 1)");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        $preco = $row['preco'];

        echo "<input type='range' name='price-min' id='price-min' value='$preco' min='0' max='100000'>";

        }

        $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT preco from carros_desc where preco = (SELECT preco FROM carros_desc ORDER BY preco DESC LIMIT 1)");

        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){

        $preco2 = $row2['preco'];

        echo "<input type='range' name='price-min' id='price-min' value='$preco2' min='0' max='100000'>
        </div>
        </div><div id='cars'>";

        }

        $result3 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT carros.modelo, carros_img.img, carros_desc.preco, carros_desc.comb FROM carros, carros_desc, carros_img WHERE carros.id = carros_desc.id_fk and carros.id = carros_img.id_fk and carros_desc.preco BETWEEN '$preco' and '$preco2' order by carros_desc.preco ASC");

                        while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){

                        $img = $row3['img'];
                        $modelo = $row3['modelo'];
                        $comb = $row3['comb'];
                        $preco3 = $row3['preco'];

                        echo "<div class='img'>
                                <a target='_blank' href='imagens/viaturas/$img'>
                                    <img src='imagens/viaturas/$img' alt='$img' width='300' height='200'>
                                </a>
                                <div class='desc'>
                                    <p>$modelo</p>
                                    <p>$comb</p>
                                    <p>$preco3</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>";
                        }
                        mysqli_close($con);
                    ?>
```

Comment: Não existe nenhum erro? O código acima representa todo o recurso que você quer utilizar?

Comment: isso é apenas o que eu fiz não sei se está certo mas é o que me pareceu ser, pela lógica.